# The opposite of Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, directory, environment-variables

Is there a method that does the opposite of the [Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx) method.

What I mean, is that upon given a path, the method returns its EnvironmentValue counterpart.

For example:

> C:\users\user\AppData\Local\foo\bar

should be turned into:

> %LOCALAPPDATA%\foo\bar

(In order for configuration files to be portable.)

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that no such method exists. Not to mention that you could have more than one environment variable pointing to the same value. Which variable would you expect to be returned in this case?

Answer (score 1):

After being told there's no such thing, I wrote a very simple version of it. If anyone has any suggestions, that'd be Awesome!

The method substitutes the longest Environment variable it can find.

```
public static class EnvironmentExtension
{
    public static string ContractEnvironmentVariables(string path)
    {
        path = Path.GetFullPath(path).ToUpperInvariant();
        DictionaryEntry currentEntry = new DictionaryEntry("","");
        foreach (object key in Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables().Keys)
        {
            string value = (string)Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()[key];
            if (path.Contains(value.ToUpperInvariant()) && value.Length > ((string)currentEntry.Value).Length)
            {
                currentEntry.Key = (string)key;
                currentEntry.Value = value;
            }
        }
        return path.Replace((string)currentEntry.Value, "%" + (string)currentEntry.Key + "%");
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably need to ignore casing. Converting everything to upper case using `ToUpperInvariant()` is a way to do that.